# aws_api_gateway_integration_response : invalid or unknown key: response_parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, terraform

I have the following configuration in Terraform:

```
// ...

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "post_pet_200_integration" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_pets_api.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.pets_resource.id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.post_pet_method.http_method}"
  status_code = "${aws_api_gateway_method_response.post_pet_200.status_code}"

  response_parameters = "foo"
}
```

When running `terraform apply`, I get:

> Errors:
>
> - aws_api_gateway_integration_response.post_pet_200_integration: :
>     invalid or unknown key: response_parameters

The documentation about [aws_api_gateway_integration_response](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_integration_response.html) says:

> **response_parameters** <- (Optional) Represents response parameters that
>   can be sent back to the caller

Why can't I use this variable ?

---

I tried the following: camelcase, with/without the s, putting in the `aws_api_gateway_method_response` or `aws_api_gateway_deployment` block instead, putting a terraform `map` variable type instead of a string. But I have the same error each time. I also tried to get inspiration from this config: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-importer, but still I got the same error.

*Edit:* Version of terraform is 0.6.14.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a bug in terraform. I would let terraform community to respond to that.

API Gateway would throw error if the format of the responseParameters is invalid, or, if the method response parameter specified doesn't exist.

The format should be like:

```
"responseParameters": {
    "method.response.header.foo": "integration.response.header.bar"              
}
```

Here is the related api reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration-response/#responseParameters